# C# api octet-stream response body to zip file

Tags: c#, rest, zip

I have a service which executes a request to a client api that returns a octet-stream response body with the Content-Disposition header in it (This api is meant to return a zip file.). I am using RestSharp and the DownloadData function to get the response as a byte array, but I want to then save the zip file to my local server.

I have tried using DotNetZip and a MemoryStream to create the zip file by using the following example:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
       zip.AddEntry("test", stream);
       zip.Save(filePath);
    }
}
```

The code above creates a zip file and an entry called test but I cannot open it.
Just to clarify, the zip file I am trying to create contains the following files and folders:

- 296927a0-5ac7-4ccd-9928-bd74ef7ae68a_20200227074457 (Root folder)

  - images (folder)

    - jpg image
    - jpg image
    - jpg image
  - details.json (file)
  - achievements.json (file)
  - evaluation.json (file)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: "I have tried using DotNetZip to create the zip file from the stream but have not had any success" what have you tried? What didn't work? I recommend you read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help page and [edit] your question to include more information for us to help you

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks for pointing me in a better direction. I hope the edits made help with answering my question.

Comment: If the API already returns a zip file you just want to do File.WriteAllBytes("test.zip")

Comment: @Milney I have tried File.WriteAllBytes and it creates a zip folder which is 364 KB, but when I attempt to open it I get a The Compressed Folder 'Folder path' is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who encounters this problem, as in saving the byte array to disk and getting a corrupted zip file, I have figured out the answer with the help of Dennis Tretyakov.

Basically, when downloading a octet-stream, the first section of is dedicated to the structure of the zip file. In my case the first section of the zip file was:

--c7c2ad44-881c-47c4-89e5-323f91b75269
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deb08d79-372d-4de2-a684-1298f25fecd9_20200310142909.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

And thereafter the actual data for the zip file appears after a linebreak.

What I ended up doing was calculating the byte count of the "header" section by converting the byte array to a string:

```
string stringEncodedBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response.RawBytes);
```

Then with knowing the starting point of the zip file data, finding the index of the starting point:

```
int headerSectionIndex = stringEncodedBytes.IndexOf("PK");
```

Once I found the index, which in my case always seems to be 178, I simple removed that part of the byte array and then copy the trimmed byte array to a new byte array and write it to disk:

```
byte[] trimmedFileBytes = new byte[response.RawBytes.Length - headerSectionIndex];
Array.Copy(response.RawBytes, headerSectionIndex, trimmedFileBytes, 0, trimmedFileBytes.Length);

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, trimmedFileBytes);
```

I would suggest that anyone struggling with the same issue, open the "corrupted" zip file in notepad++ and take a look at the first section and then determine where the data section of the zip file starts.

The initial zip file data looks like this:

[image: Initial Zip File Data]

And the trimmed zip file data looks like this:

[image: Trimmed Zip File Data]

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the fileBytes is already a zip file byte stream, what means you don't need to zip it again. Just save as file.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried File.WriteAllBytes and it creates a zip folder which is 364 KB, but when I attempt to open it I get a The Compressed Folder 'Folder path' is invalid.

Comment: Are you getting this error trying to open it programmaticaly or using some well tested tool, like 7zip ?

Comment: I get the error when trying to extract it from Windows.

Comment: and what about an API then? is it well tested? I mean can others open ZIP you are trying to open? 'cuz it sounds like API returns corrupted ZIP

Comment: When I run the api in Postman and save the response to file as a zip file, then I can extract and open it. Could it be that the contents of the file contains objects? As in some of the data contains complex objects which are generated by the clients api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209292/discussion-between-dev-101-and-dennis-tretyakov).

Answer (score 0):

So i had the same issue Dev_101 had, in which a RestResponse was corrupting the .zip file, however in my case, it was just appending an extra " on the beginning and end, so I just needed to remove the " and Base64Decode it and saved perfectly.